# Badges for answering X and asking Y number of questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

There are badges for achieving a certain amount of activity for: voting, visiting, editing, reviewing, and flagging.  But there is **no activity level badge for answering *x* number of questions, or for asking *y* number of questions**.

You could argue that doing something like this would just encourage people to answer questions even if they don't have a real answer to them, but that could easily be dealt with by only counting answer with more than 2 votes.

This would be less open to abuse than the current gold badge for voting 600 times, or the gold badge for editing 500 times, and I would argue would encourage more positive behaviour.

## Summary

**Questions** with more than 2 upvotes:
5 = Bronze
20 = Silver
80 = Gold

**Answers** with more than 2 upvotes:
15 = Bronze
50 = Silver
200 = Gold

Comment: Seeing as this is a discussion, could whoever downvoted this please give us their thoughts on where the problems with it ar so that we can all learn?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are individual SEs allowed to create badges? How much control do they have on the points/badge system?

Comment: @rk. I'm not sure, but I would be surprised if they were.  I would like to see this on more than just this site though.

Comment: I think it makes sense to have badges on these criteria. I recently saw the badges criteria and understood how thoughtful the system is; but reading this question made me wonder why not this is already there! It will definitely motivate.

Comment: Would those Bronze badges be replacing or in addition to the Teacher (first answer with a score of 1 or more) and Student (first question with a score of 1 or more)?

Comment: @norabora I would suggest them being additions to those badges.  As an aside, nice job on all the edits lately :)

Comment: @JohnGB why thank you! :)

Comment: @norabora Just stating the facts. You should join the chat room some time.  It's where all the cool kids hang out - only they're mostly nerds :)

Comment: @JohnGB I don't know how you guys focus on doing all the reviews, answering questions, etc, plus hang out in chat, plus do your actual jobs. I'd spend more time in chat but that would mean spending less time on what I'm paid to do...

Comment: @norabora nerd power! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it hasn't been answered yet. For a few years, there is badges for asking X questions with a positive record. You need at least a total on +1 for each question that should have been asked on separate days. These three badges are very close to the limits you've suggested, so I guess this answers half of your question.

[image]